# Ordenação De Dados com java e mysql

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados

Tô fazendo um trabalho pra faculdade e estou travado em uma parte, basicamente o trabalho é pegar uma serie de imagens e colocar no campo blob (esta parte está feita). A outra parte é ordenar as fotos com método escolhido que foi o bubble sort que precisa ler as series de foto para a ordenação, mas não consigo inserir um bubble sort no código. Alguém consegue me dar um help?

```
package APS;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Gabriel
 */

public class GEOP {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aps","root","root");  
  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        PreparedStatement insertFoto= con.prepareStatement("uptade geoprocessamento set photo = ? Where ID = ?");
        
        
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select ID from geoprocessamento");  
        while(rs.next()){
                        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));  
                        
                        //Carregar Foto
                        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        FileInputStream arquivo = new FileInputStream("c:\\Users\\GABRI\\Desktop\\Foto"+rs.getString(1)+ "jpeg");
                        int byteLido= arquivo.read();
                        while(byteLido != -1){
                            buffer.write(byteLido);
                            byteLido = arquivo.read();
                        }
                        //atualizar foto
                        insertFoto.setInt(2,rs.getInt(1));
                        insertFoto.setBytes(1, buffer.toByteArray());
                        insertFoto.executeUpdate();                     
        }  
        con.close();  
    }
    catch(Exception db){
        System.out.println("Erro em DB: "+db);
    }
}           
}
```

Comment: Esse código funciona? está escrito `uptade` no `prepareStatement`

Comment: Gostaria de ordenar as fotos baseada em que critério? Não poderia só fazer uma consulta com um `order by` no banco de dados?